# Snap-in not showing up in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, mmc, mmc3

I developed a snap-in for the MMC 3.0 framework using c#. The snap-in has been installed successfully on Windows XP for years now. However, I recently tried installing the snap-in on a Windows 7 PC and it does not show up in MMC Console i.e., it's not listed as a snap-in that can be added? I'm building the snap-in on a Windows XP machine. According to the InstallUtil output/log the snap-in was registered ok.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is your Windows 7 machine 64 bit? Is it possible that your snap-in is 32 bit and so not compatible with 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks David.. that pointed me in the right direction. My snap-in is 32 bit but I found on Windows 7 if you use the /32 flag when starting mmc my snap-in then appears.